# RxJS: how to reflect array of observable results in ordered to the UI?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

I have an array of observables. Each of them will make a http call to a REST endpoint and return a result so I can update the UI.

I am using zip to run them all like this:

```
Observable.zip(allTransactions).subscribe(result=> {blab});
```

In `subscribe`, I update a page-level collection, so UI gets updated via 2-way binding (angular). 
however, there are a few problems:

1) when I construct each observable in the array, I added `.delay(1000)` to it, so I expect each run will delay at least 1 second to the previous one. In fact, that's not true. Based on my log, it seems all those transactions were fired at the same time. But the `subscribe` was delayed on second. I really need them run in sequence, as the order I setup the array, because I have some dependency in those transactions. Running all together won't work for me.

2) `zip` doesn't seem to guarantee to bring back my results in ordered. So my UI is totally in random ordered. Because I was doing `this.items.push(result)`, where `items` is a variable being bound to the UI.

I am currently trying to merge all the transactions and add an empty observable with delay between every 2 transactions (still working on it).

Can anyone provide any suggestion what other alternatives I can do? or a better way I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Can You provide a reproducable example? Some codepen or jsfiddle for it?

Answer (score 1):

1) You are correct that adding .delay(1000) to all observables will not make them wait for the previous one. The delay operator will delay the execution from the moment you subscribe to them, and since you subscribe to them all at the same time and delay them for the same amount of time, they will all execute at the same time.

If you want to execute the observable in sequence, and wait for one to finish before proceeding to the next then use the flatMap operator:

```
obs1.get()
// First call
.flatMap(response1 => {

    return obs2.get(response1.something);

})  
.subscribe(response2 => {
// Result from second call
});
```

2) Looking at the [zip documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md) the result should return in an ordered list:

> Merges the specified observable sequences or Promises into one
>   observable sequence by using the selector function whenever all of the
>   observable sequences have produced an element at a corresponding
>   index. If the result selector function is omitted, a list with the
>   elements of the observable sequences at corresponding indexes will be
>   yielded.

But as you have noted: the calls are all executed simultaneously and one observable does not wait for the next one before starting.

So the call:

```
Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, obs3).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Will log:

```
[response1, response2, response3]
```